# How to take upper left corner point(X,Y) of the bounded image in cell?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

In my WinForm project have `DataGridViewImageClumn`.

After I populate the column with images(with help of Bitmap) ,
I need to take upper left corner `point(X,Y)` of the bounded image in cell.

Any idea how to implement it?

Comment: Did you try the Column Cell → Layout Alignment?

Comment: No,but i will try it.Thanks